# The ViewController design in iOS vs MVC in tradiational web apps design

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, mvc, object-oriented-design, ios

As I came from the background of webapps and move to iOS programming, I am wondering why we can't just apply the MVC design approach to native apps,

i.e. in iOS, the view and controller are tightly coupled, are there any reason?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of web applications, Model View Controller is a fairly straightforward request/response paradigm.  You push a form out to the user (the "View"), they fill it in, and then they click a Submit button.

This paradigm can be elaborated on via Javascript, AJAX, client-side validation, additional user interactivity, and so forth, but these elaborations are not, strictly speaking, part of MVC proper, and they don't change the fundamental request/response nature of the paradigm.

For those environments where you need **greater coordination between the View and the Controller,** you either use a bastardized form of MVC, or something like MVVM or MVP where those interactions are more formally specified as part of the paradigm.